How to get rows which has data set matching
I have a table which describe place where product is selling as below:



PRODUCT
Position




A
1, 2, 3


B
2


C
7,8,9, 10


D
2,3,4


E
7,8,9



I want to get Products with match two or more selling positions in hive sql
Expect result:
A,D
C,E


Why didn't you include B in with either A or D? Please explain how your logic works

To me, the logic is clear and has been explained. They want to match products where at least two positions equal. B has only one position, so it should not be selected.


You can first UNNEST the positions, this is done in CTE positions_exploded
Then it is SELF JOINED on the condition that positions should be same and product pairs should be counted only once.
Finally we count the pairs which has matching positions for 2 or more.

I have tried in postgres as I dont have hive, however I think you need to  change some of the syntax for hive, you can explode like shown in this example
Fiddle in Postgres
WITH positions_exploded AS (
    SELECT
        product,
        unnest(position) AS pos
    FROM
        product_position
)
  ,
 
matched_products AS (
    SELECT
        p1.product AS product1,
        p2.product AS product2,
        COUNT(*) AS common_positions
    FROM
        positions_exploded p1
    JOIN
        positions_exploded p2
    ON
        p1.pos = p2.pos AND p1.product < p2.product
    GROUP BY
        p1.product, p2.product
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) >= 2
)
SELECT
    product1,
    product2
FROM
    matched_products;

Output



product1
product2




A
D


C
E



You can also concat the output in comma separated values like
STRING_AGG(product1 || ',' || product2, ', ') AS product_pairs

